# EF5: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Nullable System.Decimal Median

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF5 Code first. When I execute my query:

```
var priceIndexQuery = from r in unitOfWork.Repository<StockIndexPriceResult>()
                                      where request.CalculateModel.StockCompanies.Contains(r.StockCompanyId)
                                            && r.StockIndexId == request.CalculateModel.StockIndexId
                                            && r.ResultDate >= dateFiveYearsAgo
                                      orderby r.ResultDate descending
                                      group r by r.ResultDate
                                          into g
                                          select g;
```

and then:

```
var query = priceIndexQuery.Select(g => new CalculateAggregateModel
                                                    {
                                                        ResultDate = g.Key,
                                                        Value = g.Median(p => p.Result ?? 0),
                                                        PeriodType = "Day"
                                                    });

                                    resultData = query.ToList();
```

I got excpetion on **query.ToList();** What I know so far is that MSSQL can't execute **Median** function. Is any way I could solve it ?

Comment: You can call `AsEnumerate()` before your select. This will force the query to execute on database **at this point**, and then continue in memory. Make sure to only select as much data as you need, not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework can't translate you Median method into SQL, so you need to query database before executing your Median method.
Try to execute `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` right after your first query:

```
var priceIndexQuery = (from r in unitOfWork.Repository<StockIndexPriceResult>()
                                      where request.CalculateModel.StockCompanies.Contains(r.StockCompanyId)
                                            && r.StockIndexId == request.CalculateModel.StockIndexId
                                            && r.ResultDate >= dateFiveYearsAgo
                                      orderby r.ResultDate descending
                                      group r by r.ResultDate
                                          into g
                                          select g).ToList();
```